# I need to resize my search bar based on the window resizing and I need make a function for the search bar resizing code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to using the code that gets the screen size with the code that resizes the search bar together. At the moment all its doing is resizing the search bar on the biggest resolution. Here's a link to an example http://www.jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/R7kSA. You need to keep changing the size of the separator and running the code at different sizes to see the difference which is the issue but I just thought I should mention it.

this code gets the screen size:

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
```

this code gives me the size upon resizing the window:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
      window.x = x;
   });
});
```

this code re sizes the search bar based on the screen size. I need to put this code that's doing the resizing into a function so I don't have keep reusing code.

```
if (window.x >= 1200) {

    $('#search_bar_box').focus(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '600px'
        }, 500, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

    $('#search_bar_box').blur(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 0.1, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

} else if (window.x >= 992 && window.x < 1200) {

    $('#search_bar_box').focus(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '350px'
        }, 500, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

    $('#search_bar_box').blur(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 0.1, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

} else if (window.x >= 768 && window.x < 992) {

    $('#search_bar_box').focus(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '100px'
        }, 500, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

    $('#search_bar_box').blur(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 0.1, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

} else {
    //default
}
```

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle ?

Comment: as window.x is going to be changed, so you need to put the if else condition in the focus/blur functions. Also I think this can be done in pure css3(media-queries, transitions).

Comment: You need to keep changing the size of the separator and running the code at different sizes to see the difference. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/R7kSA/

Comment: @Andrew - I need a solution which is compatible across all browsers including other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute your search-bar resize code on window `resize()` event, that's how I got your code working. See this jsiffdle: [jsfiddle.net/R7kSA/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/R7kSA/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        /* winWidth() is the function for getting the screen size. 
           set() is the function that handles the search bar resize and
           accepts the argument value for 'x'             
        */
        set(winWidth());
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```